# PHP session not saved after curl call

Tags: php, session, curl, session-variables

I need to authenticate my user through a curl script

```
session_start();
$_POST["username"]= "user";
$_POST["password"]= "password";

$ch = curl_init();

$url = 'signin.php';


 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($_POST));
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

 $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);
 curl_close($ch);
```

The signin.php makes another curl call to an api, I made sure that signin.php returns all required information, sets all required session variables, returns an array:

```
echo json_encode(array(
            'success' => true,
            'ALLSESSION' => $_SESSION,
            'error'=> ""
        ));
```

the ALLSESSION is returning the correct session variables, but they are not accessible directly, I mean I cant use $_SESSION["userid"], its not existent in the array of sessions.

How to preserve the session between the 2 pages?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps a simple reassignment like:

    if (!isset($_SESSION)) { $_SESSION = ALLSESSION; }

Comment: @ThomasPowers I havent thought of this idea though its a good one, but isnt session supposed to presist between the 2 pages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the client is not remembering/transmitting the PHP session id.

When an HTTP client makes a request to a php script (via an HTTP server), it must include the session id in the request if it wishes to continue a previously started session. This can be done either in the HTTP headers as a cookie or as a URL parameter (named *PHPSESSID* by default). 
If you do not want to use PHP's default session variable name, or if you want to use a POST variable instead of a URL parameter, then you can use any request variable or URL parameter you wish (whether it be GET, POST, or COOKIE), but then you will need to manually interpret this variable on the server-side.

Here are three solutions, in order of most recommended to least recommended.

1. Turn on cookie support in cUrl **or**
2. Pass the session id as a URL parameter **or**
3. Pass the session id as a request variable (post/cookie) or a URL parameter that does not use the name expected by PHP, and then manually start the session on the server-side using that session id.

### Solution #1: Turn on cookie support in cUrl

PHP uses the session id in the cookie to reload your session data each time you make a request from that client.

In this case, the client is cUrl.  You need to setup your cUrl request to allow/use cookies.
This is done by setting the [CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR.html) and [CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE.html) options.

```
session_start();
$_POST["username"]= "user";
$_POST["password"]= "password";

$ch = curl_init();

$url = 'signin.php';

//Name of a file to store cookie data in.
//If the file does not exist, it will be created.  
//cUrl (or your web server) needs to have write permissions to the folder.
$cookieFile = "/some/writable/folder/filename";


curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($_POST));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

//Tell cUrl about the cookie file
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);  //tell cUrl where to write cookie data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile); //tell cUrl where to read cookie data from

$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);
curl_close($ch);
```

Any subsequent cUrl calls that use *$cookieFile* for CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE will have the same session data as prior calls.

### Solution #2: Pass the session id in the URL query string using the expected parameter name (PHPSESSID by default, but this can be changed)

You can append the session id to all urls like this:
somepage.php?PHPSESSID=sessionidgoeshere

"PHPSESSID" is the variable name that is used by default in PHP.  If the server is [setup to use a non-default name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php), then you would need to use that variable name instead.

With solution #2, you will still need to store the session id on the client-side somehow.

### Solution #3: Pass the session id as a request variable or a URL parameter and then manually start the session on the server-side using that session id.

This solution is not recommended for normal situations.  Unlike the previous solutions, this one requires changes to the server-side script as well as the client-side (cUrl). This solution is only useful if you specifically want to send the session id as something other than a URL parameter or cookie, or if you want to use a variable name other than the name that the server is expecting.
Place the [following code in your server-side PHP that is handling the request, prior to starting the session](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php):
`session_id($_POST[<param_name>]);` or `session_id($_GET[<param_name>]);` or `session_id($_COOKIE[<param_name>]);`

I suggest using Solution #1 unless you have a compelling reason not to.

Also, PHP doesn't care whether the request is a GET or a POST or any other HTTP request method.  Regardless of the HTTP request method, if the session id is [passed as a URL parameter or in a cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php), then the related session will persist on the server-side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try the first solution, but I needed to ask do I have to use the 2 lines in the first call only or both?

Comment: In the first call, assuming you don't care if they had already previously authenticated, you can omit the CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE setting.  You only need CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE if you want to read previously saved cookies (in other words, if you want to persist an existing session).

Comment: HI, I'm having the same problem. I added the 2 lines that you said in the first solution but I still have tha same, So, do I have to add something in the script that I'm calling? or there's a way to know if the cookie file is created sucesfully?

Comment: To know if the cookie file is created successfully, you can look on your hard drive at the specified location ($cookieFile) and see if it exists, or if you want to do it programmatically you can use `file_exists($cookieFile)`.  Otherwise I think I'd need to see code to diagnose further.  You should create a new question for that.

Comment: I think solution #3 is unnecessary, slightly ambiguous, and veers a bit away from the spirit of the OP's question.  I left it though, because it was helpful to someone and so maybe it will be helpful to someone else.