# cURL Login and set sessions

Tags: php, curl

http://example.com/auth/signin?email=name@example.com&password=test123

that page prints this xml code,

```
{
  "token": "exampletoken",
"user": {
"email": "name@example.com",
"hostUrl": "http://example.com/admin",
"schema": "example",
"firstName": "",
"lastName": "",
"photo": "",
"id": 1,
"createdAt": "2016-13-28T14:45:23.000Z",
"updatedAt": "2016-13-28T14:45:23.000Z"
}
}
```

and i want to set the token as session and get html://example.com/admin/index.php contents with get_file_contents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cURL login session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515145/curl-login-session)

Comment: Maybe possible for you but i dont need do this with cookies, I need do that with sessions.

Comment: Well, anyway, you can find the answer on Stack Overflow - here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389151/php-session-not-saved-after-curl-call